# Database normalization for sten percentile t-score

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I just started modeling my database in MySQL.

So I have a table named "norms" with the following columns:

id (int) -- primary key 
fk_category_id (int) --- foreign key from anothe table 
raw_score_min (int) --- lowerbound score needed for range 
raw_score_max (max) --- upperbound score needed for range 
 
sten (int) --- standard ten (value 1-10) remarks 
percentile (int) --- percentage remark (value 1-100) 
t-score (int) --- another remarks that has weird correlation 
fk_classification_id --- foreign key from another table

Now, not every row in this database will use sten, percentile and t-score.

There will be most cases where only one of the three will be used.
However there are special cases wherein two out of three will be used (i.e. sten and percentile)

So if the rows pile up, the table will have lots of rows with wasted column of 0 value for sten, percentil and t-score

Is there any way I can avoid that waste using normalization? Thank you!

---

UPDATE:
I forgot to tell that as the system goes by, there might be additional type to "standards" (sten, t-score, percentile) such as CSQ or other standard. Following the table above, it might mean that I should add a new column everytime there's a new type of "standard".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new table, e.g. `stats`, which will contain the standard ten, percentile, and t-score values for those records which have them.

```
CREATE TABLE stats
(
    id int,          -- same id as used in the norms table
    sten int,
    percentile int,
    t-score int
);
```

Note that the gain here occurs because you won't be allocating any database storage to those records which do not have any stats.  Contrast this with the denormalized approach in your original problem, where you might be storing zero values for that record.

**Update:**

If you really need to add stats/columns, then I expect it to be a hassle with either my approach or your original approach.  By normalizing the database, you will still get a potential gain.

But perhaps the new stats could be calculated on the fly rather than being persisted to the database.  This would avoid the problem of having to keep adding new columns.

Comment: Hi Tim! Thanks for the fast reply. By the way I have an update for the question, please see above. Will you still advise the same answer?

Comment: Thanks! Accepting this answer since I followed this advice, this makes total sense and has follow up answer

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, you can avoid that. For example you could do a separate table `norm_sten`, `norm_percentile` and `norm_tscore` with a reference to `norm."id"`.

However, you should carefully check if this doesn't overly complicate your application logic. Since an integer field only uses 4 bytes, you usually only run into table space issues unless you have millions and millions of records.

Comment: Hi Bjoern! Thanks for the fast reply. You also have similar answer to Tim above, so it means that might be a valid answer. By the way I have an update for the question, please see above. Will you still advise the same answer?

Comment: Yes, it still is valid. Depending on the needs of your applications and your DB server it might be overkill or necessary, so only a general reply can be given.